# Visual Studio 2015 regular crash

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2015

I had no major problems with Visual Studio 2013 (or any VS version all the way back to VS6), but 2015 crashes or hangs several times a day. I've ran it on two different machines, fresh Windows 10 installs with the same crashes on both.

EDIT: This question originally referred to VS 2015 Update 2, but I've edited it several times as each update has been released.

There are many different crashes and hangs and other errors. The most common one as of September 2016 is this:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.GetInvoker()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.InvokeOnUIThread(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.InvokableBase)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke(System.Action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper+<>c__DisplayClass23_0+<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper+<InvokeAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TaskSchedulerService.VsUIThreadScheduler+<ExecuteTaskInRPCPriority>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The crashes occur at random times. Starting a build, resuming after breaking, changing from debug to release, hitting Save All, switching files, even when idle.

**Update:**
I've given up. VS 2015 is just an embarrassing mess. Between the crashes and other broken features (such as Edit & Continue, broken debugger, breakpoints failing etc. etc.) it is close to unusable for any serious sized C++ project. I've gone back to VS 2013 which runs faster and is far more reliable.

Comment: Have you tried Debugging Tools for Windows? Or remotely debug it from a healthy VS.

Comment: Just this week my Visual Studio Started to crash really often. I can't use it. For no obvious reason. When idle, when opening something, when editing text. Any time. I have removed all extensions I could and no luck. I installed the hotfix for VS 2015 Update 3. No help. I have no idea what to do. Re-install OS form clean? And then VS? I have Windows 7 64bit

Comment: I have the same in VS2019. The fix is a Windows Reset.